# Default Country prop not detecting the country code MazPhoneNumberInput

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

When I set the default country to Canada it doesn't detect the country code present in the phone number. For example, if the phone number is `+15062345678` then it shows the +1 attached to the input.
[image]

What I want is to remove the country code present on the input and autodetect it instead.

Here is my code

```js
<MazPhoneNumberInput
                  :model-value="phone"
                  show-code-on-list
                  color="info"
                  :preferred-countries="['FR', 'BE', 'DE', 'US', 'GB']"
                  :ignored-countries="['AC']"
                  default-country-code="CA"
                  @input="v$.phone.$touch"
                  @update="validPhoneNumber = $event"
                />
```

The phone value is coming from the backend and is `+15062345678`

Comment: I'd suggest to post this question to the github issues of the library, since it's only related to it.

Comment: I did but no response so I posted here just in case